# Homestead Installation: Shared folder map changes not working

Tags: laravel, homestead

I'm trying to install Homestead on a Mac using VirtualBox and when I edit the homstead.yaml file to change the location of my local shared folder the change never registers, as I always get the error

The host path of the shared folder is missing: ~/Code

when I vagrant up.
When I performed bash init.sh I was asked to overwrite homestead.yaml, after.sh, and aliases. I've been having this problem for a while now and have tried many different things but nothing seems to work. I new with Laravel and would appreciate some help. Thanks!

Comment: did u install Homestead successfully ?? is your vagrant box is running ??

Answer (score 0):

In your Homested.yaml file but make sure you have folder in your **C:\Code**

```
folders:
    - map: C:/Code
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: homestead.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public
```

Comment: My issue is when I direct the folder map to another location than C:\Code and run vagrant up, it still looks for the Code folder instead of the folder I am directing it to.

Comment: delet your **.homstead** and **Homestead** folder again do this steps `git clone https://github.com/laravel/homestead.git Homestead` `bash init.sh` just idea

Comment: Yes I've done that many times.  Homestead if up and running on VirtualBox but I am having this specific folder issue.